# MS Word batch hyperlink

Tags: ms-word

I would like to know if there is a way to create hyperlinks from a text in bulk.
I have the following text:
www. abc .com/pictures/T_1.jpg
www. abc. com/pictures/T_2.jpg
www. abc. com/pictures/T_3.jpg
www. abc. com/pictures/T_4.jpg
Each text is a link in its own right, but if I select all and press Ctrl+K, I cannot create a hyperlink that takes the text as a weblink. I can do it one by one. If I select any of the text and press Ctrl+K, it'll give me [www.abc.com/pictures/T_1.jpg](http://www.abc.com/pictures/T_1.jpg) as the web address for that link, but not in bulk. How to do it?

Note: spaces in the links to avoid posting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this,

1. Paste links in word and separate them by a paragraph,
2. Select the links and Insert -> Table -> Convert to Table,
3. View -> Macros -> View Macros and create the following macro named BH

Sub BH()
Dim Rng As Range, TblCell As Cell, StrTxt As String
With Selection
If .Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then Exit Sub
For Each TblCell In .Cells
Set Rng = TblCell.Range
With Rng
.End = .End - 1
StrTxt = .Text
.Text = ""
End With
ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Rng, _
Address:="Address", SubAddress:="SubAddress", _
ScreenTip:="", TextToDisplay:=StrTxt, Target:="_blank"
Next
End With
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

For what you have described:

```
Sub ConvertURLTextsToHyperlinksInDoc()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "[wh][wt][wtps]{1,3}[./][!^13^t^l ^s]{1,}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Format = False
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
    If .Characters.Last Like "[:;.,(?)!})]" Then .End = .End - 1
    .Hyperlinks.Add .Duplicate, .Text, , , .Text
    .Start = .Hyperlinks(1).Range.End
    .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The text you posted, though, does not include valid URLs - there are spaces either side of abc...